# How shall I test the following method in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I'm writing unit test cases for the method:

```
initialize: function() {
    name = 'loadContent';
    if ($('#search') == null || $('#searchA') == undefined ) {
        loadResource('right', 'righ.html', function() {
            loadResource('left', 'left.html', function() {
                constructHtml("t");
            });
        });
    } else {
        loadResource('right', 'righ.html', function() {
            constructHtml("t");
        });
    }
}
```

For the above method, I have written the following test cases:

```
describe("Test",function(){
    describe("Search",function(){

    beforeEach(function() {
        spyOn(window,'loadResource');
    });

    it("loads called",function(){
        window.initialize()
        expect(loadResource).toHaveBeenCalledWith('right','righ.html',jasmine.any(Function));
    })

    });
});
```

Aprat from this what all other test cases I can right with respect to the method `initialize`?